# Does it make sense to use PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor with Spring's JdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Title speaks for itself.

Is PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor used solely for JPA implementations or is it relevant to use it with Spring's JdbcTemplate too?

And if there are two datasources needed each with their own JPA entity manager and transaction manager, do I still only need to specify one PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor for the entire application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The auto-award bounty answer is wrong**

*~~~The correct answer is as follows~~~*

I believe I've discovered the answer here: 
http://www.deroneriksson.com/tutorials/java/spring/introduction-to-the-spring-framework/component-scanning-and-repository

> The @Repository annotation can have a special role when it comes to converting exceptions to Spring-based unchecked exceptions. Recall that the JdbcTemplate handled this task for us. When we work with Hibernate, we’re not going to work with a Spring template that handles this conversion of Hibernate-based exceptions to Spring-based exceptions. As a result, in order to handle this conversion automatically, Hibernate DAOs annotated with @Repository will have their Hibernate exceptions rethrown as Spring exceptions using a PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.

Further reading: http://www.deroneriksson.com/tutorials/java/spring/introduction-to-the-spring-framework/hibernate-daos

The paragraph above explicitly says: 
***Recall that the JdbcTemplate handled this task for us***

So, to answer my own question, there is no need to use PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor with jdbcTemplate

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, The Spring exception translation mechanism can be applied transparently to all beans annotated with `@Repository` – by defining an exception translation bean post processor bean in the Context:

```
<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
   class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

As per it [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.html)

> Bean post-processor that automatically applies persistence exception translation to any bean marked with Spring's @Repository
>   annotation, adding a corresponding
>   PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor to the exposed proxy (either an
>   existing AOP proxy or a newly generated proxy that implements all of
>   the target's interfaces).
>
> Translates native resource exceptions to Spring's DataAccessException hierarchy. Autodetects beans that implement the
>   PersistenceExceptionTranslator interface, which are subsequently asked
>   to translate candidate exceptions.
>   All of Spring's applicable resource factories (e.g. LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) implement the
>   PersistenceExceptionTranslator interface out of the box. As a
>   consequence, all that is usually needed to enable automatic exception
>   translation is marking all affected beans (such as Repositories or
>   DAOs) with the @Repository annotation, along with defining this
>   post-processor as a bean in the application context.

So you can use it with Jdbctemplate as well as with any Jpa vendor implementation

As per is doc `All of Spring's applicable resource factories (e.g. LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) implement the PersistenceExceptionTranslator interface out of the box`, I think you still need to use PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor, because it used to translate all errors generated during the persistence process (HibernateExceptions, PersistenceExceptions...) into DataAccessException objects.